# On Premises Application to AWS LIft And Shift Application Migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, lift, shift

On Premises Application is going to move to AWS Cloud in EC2 as AWS Lift and Shift MIgration.Currently On-Premises applications are running in Tomcat. Once we are going to migrate it to AWS as a Lift and Shift, we need all App logs generated should be stroed in S3 Bucket countinuously. Some one please help to advise as not sure how tomcat will write app logs to S3 bucket. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by installing Cloudwatch Agent on the EC2 and then configuring it to push the specific tomcat log files to Cloudwatch.
You can follow the below blog post. The blog post is for apache server , you will need to update the log file paths according to the tomcat installation.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/simplifying-apache-server-logs-with-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights/

To push the logs further into S3 follow the below article link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html